# Find and use the transpose of a linear operator in python

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, transpose

I have a complicated linear system $y = Ax$ where I cannot specify the matrix A, I can however write a function that computes Ax, and I have made this into a linear operator.

I need to find $A^T$.

I have tried finding $A^T$ by hand but it is becoming tricky.

I found that scipy has a built in function .transpose(), I have tried using this with a simple example,

```
def mv(v):
    return np.array([2*v[0]- v[1], 3*v[1]])
```

```
A = LinearOperator((2,2), matvec=mv)
C = A.transpose()
```

but then when I try to use this it doesn't seem to work. I tried comparing the results

```
A.matvec(np.ones(2))
array([1., 3.])
```

```
C.rmatvec(np.ones(2))
array([1., 3.])
```

but the results are the same? I'm not sure why this is, surely the second result should be [2, 2].

Comment: where are you importing `LinearOperator` from?

Comment: from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator

Comment: Why should it be `[2,2]`?

Comment: I thought that it would be finding the transpose multiplied by A.

Comment: 'transpose' of what?  Normally transpose is defined for a matrix.  LinearOperator extends that concept, making a new LinearOperator that should be usable in the same way as `A.T` would.  May be I should have added  an example where `Ax` uses a matrix and the usual matrix multipliers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the transpose of a function you would need to use automatic differentiation which python has in built tools for. I managed, in the end, to find the transpose of my linear operator by hand.

Answer (score 0):

For a 2d array, `M`:

```
In [28]: M = np.array([[1,3,2],[2,1,2],[5,2,1]]); x=np.array([1,2,3])
```

The transpose lets us switch the order:

```
In [29]: M@x
Out[29]: array([13, 10, 12])   
In [30]: x@M.T
Out[30]: array([13, 10, 12])
```

Is that what your `C` does? Implementing the `rmatvec` inplace of the `A.matvec`.

Trying to use `matvec` on `C` produces an error. `C` itself is a `LinearOperator`, one that (somehow) references the operations defined for `A`.

```
In [40]: C.matvec([1,1])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[40], line 1
----> 1 C.matvec([1,1])

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\_interface.py:232, in LinearOperator.matvec(self, x)
    229 if x.shape != (N,) and x.shape != (N,1):
    230     raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
--> 232 y = self._matvec(x)
    234 if isinstance(x, np.matrix):
    235     y = asmatrix(y)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\_interface.py:583, in _TransposedLinearOperator._matvec(self, x)
    581 def _matvec(self, x):
    582     # NB. np.conj works also on sparse matrices
--> 583     return np.conj(self.A._rmatvec(np.conj(x)))

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\_interface.py:535, in _CustomLinearOperator._rmatvec(self, x)
    533 func = self.__rmatvec_impl
    534 if func is None:
--> 535     raise NotImplementedError("rmatvec is not defined")
    536 return self.__rmatvec_impl(x)

NotImplementedError: rmatvec is not defined
```

The key is that for `C`, `matvec` is implemented with a `A.rmatvec`:

```
np.conj(self.A._rmatvec(np.conj(x)))
```

I haven't worked a lot with this `LinearOperator` class, but I view it was an abstract class that can be used in iterative solvers in much the same as a 'conventional' 2d array, except that all it has to define is one or more operations like `matvec`.  In your case it's the `mv` function.

From the `LinearOpertor` docs:

```
shape : tuple
    Matrix dimensions (M, N).
matvec : callable f(v)
    Returns returns A * v.
rmatvec : callable f(v)
    Returns A^H * v, where A^H is the conjugate transpose of A.
```

### contrived example

Define a `rmatvec` for `A`:

```
In [51]: def mv(v):
    ...:     return np.array([2*v[0]- v[1], 3*v[1]])
    ...: def rmv(v):
    ...:     return np.array([2*v[1]- v[0], 3*v[0]]) 
    ...: A = linalg.LinearOperator((2,2), matvec=mv, rmatvec=rmv)
    ...: C = A.transpose()

In [52]: A.matvec((1,6))
Out[52]: array([-4, 18])

In [53]: A.rmatvec((1,6))
Out[53]: array([11,  3])

In [54]: A.rmatvec((6,1))
Out[54]: array([-4, 18])
```

Notice how `C` just switches the roles of `matvec` and `rmatvec`:

```
In [55]: C.matvec((1,6))
Out[55]: array([11,  3])

In [56]: C.rmatvec((1,6))
Out[56]: array([-4, 18])
```

`transpose` will also change the `shape` of the operator.  If `A` takes (2,) and returns a (3,), it has shape (3,2); `C` has shape (2,3), consistent with being a right-hand operator:

```
In [58]: def mv(v):
    ...:     return np.array([2*v[0]- v[1], 3*v[1],0]) 
    ...: A = linalg.LinearOperator((3,2), matvec=mv)
    ...: C = A.transpose()

In [59]: A
Out[59]: <3x2 _CustomLinearOperator with dtype=float64>
In [60]: C
Out[60]: <2x3 _TransposedLinearOperator with dtype=float64>
```

Comment: I see, so using .transpose() is a way of setting a new linear operator as your pre-defined transpose? I guess I am looking for a function that can find my transpose for me as I am unable to define it myself?

Comment: Why do you need the transpose?  I wonder if you are confusing transpose and inverse,

Comment: I definitely needed the transpose.